# Octave Contour plots

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure, contour

```
x = linspace(-10, 10, 100);
y = linspace(-10, 10, 100);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x, y);

t2= X.^2 + (Y.^2);

contour(x,y,t2,'showtext','on');
```

When I run the above code in octave, I am getting concentric elliptical figures in contour plots. I expected to be a concentric circle figures . What is wrong in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is concentric circle figure. Add

```
axis equal
```

to see it more clearly.

Comment: I am sorry. It is not concentric figure. I have attached my figure.

![contour line of eqn](http://s30.postimg.org/eez9j66mp/test.jpg)

Comment: Where exactly do we add 'axis equal' ?